# Event inside the button click not worked in the Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a plugin based on [this-one boilerplate](https://github.com/acanimal/jQuery-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/jquery-plugin.js)

However I am stuck. Here is the my code.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = 'ReservationTableJQPlugin';


    function Plugin(element, options) {

        // Store a reference to the source element
        this.container = element;
        this.$container = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function () {

            this.$htmlbtn = '' +
          '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnPrevWeek"> Geri</button> ' +
          '<button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnTodayWeek">Bugun</button>' +
          ' <button  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs  btnNextWeek">Ileri</button>';
            this.$container.append(this.$htmlbtn).append(this._renderTable());
            this.$tbody = this.$container.find('table').addClass("table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed");

            this.$btnMenus = $('.btnMenu');
            this.$btnNextClickEvent = $('.btnNextWeek');
            //I am binding all clcick events here
            this._btnClickEvents(this.$tbody,this._appendTable());

        },

        destroy: function () {

            // Remove any attached data from your plugin
            this.$container.empty();
            this.$container.removeData();
            this.$btnNextClickEvent.off('.' + pluginName);
            this.$btnMenus.off('.' + pluginName);

        },


        _appendTable :function() {
            this.$tbody.append(this._renderTable());
        },

        _renderTable: function () {

            return (this._renderHeader() + this._renderContent());
        },

        _renderContent: function () {
        },

        _renderHeader: function () {

        },


        _getData: function () {
        },

        _btnClickEvents: function (that,fnc) {

            var fncx = fnc;
            this.$btnMenus.on('click.' + pluginName, function () {

                alert('working');
            });

            this.$btnNextClickEvent.on('click.' + pluginName,"button", function () {

                that.empty();
                fncx();
                //here givea me error,saying this__renderTable not found.
                //also that.empty();  functon not clear html element
            });

        }
    };


    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        var args = arguments;

        if (options === undefined || typeof options === 'object') {
            // Creates a new plugin instance, for each selected element, and
            // stores a reference withint the element's data
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
                }
            });
        } else if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' && options !== 'init') {
            // Call a public pluguin method (not starting with an underscore) for each 
            // selected element.
            if (Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1).length == 0 && $.inArray(options, $.fn[pluginName].getters) != -1) {
                // If the user does not pass any arguments and the method allows to
                // work as a getter then break the chainability so we can return a value
                // instead the element reference.
                var instance = $.data(this[0], 'plugin_' + pluginName);
                return instance[options].apply(instance, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
            } else {
                // Invoke the speficied method on each selected element
                return this.each(function () {
                    var instance = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
                    if (instance instanceof Plugin && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {
                        instance[options].apply(instance, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * Default options
     */
    $.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
        defaultOption: "I'm a default option",
        url: "ReservationPage/Index",
        searchId: 5,
        startHour: 6,
        weeks: [],
        tableCss: {}


    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

My problem is as mention inside code, `this.$btnNextClickEvent` not work properly and gives me and error "this._renderTable not found".
Only what I wanna do is, when the btnNextClick button clear all html in table and add new datas into table.

Comment: Inside an event call, `this.$btnNextClickEvent.on('click.' + pluginName,"button", ...`, `this` does not represent your object anymore. So the solution is declare a variable like `var _this = this;` and then, inside the event handler, use `_this` instead of `this`

Comment: declare a variable like var _this = this; where inside this._btnClickEvents?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the code, sorry. I though you were using `this` inside the event.